# Compatibility between the source and the boundary condition for an Helmholtz-type equation

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, ap.analysis-of-pdes, sobolev-spaces, traces

Let $\Omega$ an open, convex, bounded domain in $\mathbb{R}^3$, and let us fix also $z\in\mathbb{C}\setminus\mathbb{R}$. Given $\phi\in H^{3/2}(\partial\Omega)$, I would like to show the existence of a function $f\in L^2(\mathbb{R}^3)$ such that:

(i) $f(x)=0$ for $x\in\Omega$

(ii) $\|f\|_{L^2(\mathbb{R}^3)}\leq C\|\phi\|_{H^{3/2}(\partial\Omega)}$, for some absolute constant $C$ (independent on $\phi$)

(iii) the equation

$$\begin{cases}
(-\Delta-z)u=f\\
u\,_{|\partial\Omega}=\phi
\end{cases}
$$
admits a solution $u\in H^2(\mathbb{R}^3)$.

EDIT: It is sufficient to prove the following fact, which I think is known but I'm unable to find a reference. Given $\phi\in H^{3/2}(\partial\Omega)$, the Helmholtz equation

$$\begin{cases}
(-\Delta-z)u=0&x\in\Omega\\
u(x)=\phi(x)&x\in\partial\Omega
\end{cases}
$$

admits a solution $u\in H^2(\Omega)$, such that $\|u\|_{H^2(\Omega)}\lesssim\|\phi\|_{H^{3/2}(\partial\Omega)}$.

Thank you for any suggestion.

Comment: Concerning your edit, since $\phi\in H^\frac{3}{2}(\partial\Omega)$ then you can find an extension $g\in H^2(\Omega)$; this is the trace Theorem and your domain is not pathological, so I think it is not hard to find a reference, e.g. a book of Triebel. Then you have to solve $(-\Delta - z)v = (\Delta + z)g\in L^2$, where $u=g+v$; here $v$ is unknown and $g$ is given. Existence and regularity is known, e.g. Evans' book on PDEs.